# Splitting up react js components into separate files -- and handling the creation of a dashboard based application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking at using reactjs as a framework to manage/control the various chart widgets.

-- when I started looking to place these components into separate js files -- undefined errors started appearing.

-- then how to structure how the charts should be rendered on a panel, how interactions could be implemented -- master/slave relationships -- update cta

http://jsfiddle.net/cfrapLma/28/

```
var config = [{
              "width": 200,
              "height": 200,
              "type": "piechart",
              "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetCars"
          }, {
              "width": 100,
              "height": 100,
              "type": "barchart",
              "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetBoats"
          },
          {
              "width": 200,
              "height": 200,
              "type": "piechart",
              "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetCars"
          },
          {
              "width": 200,
              "height": 200,
              "type": "linechart",
              "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetCars"
          }];



          var MultipleCharts = React.createClass({
              getChart: function(config) {
                  switch (config.type) {

                      case 'piechart':
                          return <PieChart width={config.width} height={config.height} service={config.service} />
                      case 'barchart':
                          return <BarChart width={config.width} height={config.height} service={config.service} />
                      case 'linechart':
                          return <LineChart width={config.width} height={config.height} service={config.service} />
                  }
              },

              render: function () {
                  var config = this.props.config;

                  return (
                      <div>
                          {config.map((chartConfig, index) => {
                              return (
                                  <div key={index} className={'holder' + index}>
                                      {this.getChart(chartConfig)}
                                  </div>
                              )
                          })}
                      </div>
                  );
              }
          });

          var PieChart = React.createClass({
              componentDidMount: function () {
                  var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
                  console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
                  // set el height and width etc.
              },
              render: function () {
                  return (
                      <div className="piechart" data-role="piechart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                          data-service={this.props.service}>pie.
                      </div>
                  );
              }
          });

          var LineChart = React.createClass({
              componentDidMount: function () {
                  var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
                  console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
                  // set el height and width etc.
              },
              render: function () {
                  return (
                      <div className="linechart" data-role="linechart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                          data-service={this.props.service}>line.
                      </div>
                  );
              }
          });



          var BarChart = React.createClass({
              componentDidMount: function () {
                  var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
                  console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
                  // set el height and width etc.
              },
              render: function () {
                  return (
                      <div className="barchart" data-role="barchart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                          data-service={this.props.service}>bar.
                      </div>
                  );
              }
          });


          ReactDOM.render(
              <MultipleCharts config={config} />,
              document.getElementById('example')
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some build tools like webpack or gulp. I am provides an example that how you should do it.

https://github.com/OnlyRefat/Example

It will help to you write moduler code. You can write code in separate files easily.

Comment: What if you aren't running node - and using cdn components

Comment: If you check all the best practices available on the web you will find that everyone is using npm with that.

Comment: I've never really had to setup a node project - also the api work I've made is using codeignitor

Comment: is there a way to use require? or webpack in this form?

Comment: This is not a node project. It is a frontend work that used npm. You can make call to api using ajax from this app. It is not dependent that the api is using php or node  or anything.

Comment: sure - but wouldn't you need to get node running to install and run gulp?

Comment: thats right. Everyone tries to use that cause it automates the frontend development. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684041/what-is-the-purposes-of-javascript-build-tools

Comment: So you are saying - just get node in place, get in place to do the build -- but still keep the codeignitor site handling the api in place. eg.. no need to do a complete sql to nosql mongodb conversion and have node also take over the api work?

Comment: i would prefer to keep the API and the frontend React work in different place or you can say decouple the frontend and backend.  React is good for his data manipulation nature. So it would be great.

Comment: Well there is a bounty on offer here - to show me the ways -- including how the data should be handled with react to other systems like d3. I was going to use reactjs to handle placeholder elements for the charts, in which then after rendering the d3 gets invoked and does the api call on its end - feed the chart the data from the codeignitor api service  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006469/reactjs-dashboard-multiple-instances-with-an-array-of-parameters